# What does this javascript code do?How does it work?

Tags: javascript

I know this seems basic but i am new and trying to get a grasp of what this actually means please help.

Ive tried to replicate the following however i am finding it difficult because i don't really understand what this code does.

```
function animate_string(id) 
{
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var textNode = element.childNodes[0]; // assuming no other children
    var text = textNode.data;

setInterval(function () 
{
 text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
  textNode.data = text;
}, 100);
}
```

This is apparently supposed to animate the string id passed as a parameter (id), and the interval doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: It acts as a sort of mimic for the `<marquee>` tag. It's working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4rxytkjL/

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Create a function called animate_string with id as parameter.
function animate_string(id) 
{
    // Search a HTML element with the given parameter id
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    
    // Childnodes gives a list of al the childnodes, childNodes[0] gives the first one
    // (In this case, the only one)
    var textNode = element.childNodes[0];
    
    // Save the text from that first child node into variable.
    var text = textNode.data;
    
    // Set interval repeats the function given as the first parameter
    // and the time to wait in MS as second one. In this case 100 ms
    setInterval(function () 
    {
     // Resave the text as the last letter of the text 
     // + the whole text minus the last character.
     text = text[text.length - 1] + text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
     
     // Show this new text
     textNode.data = text;
    }, 100);
}

// Let's run the function!
animate_string('idElement')
```

```html
<div id="idElement">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: No problem! If you have any extra question for this example, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: What is that? Why does that marquee effect is seen? And how?